# Cannot load Creole.xml GATE

Tags: java, gate

I am trying to embed GATE to my java project. I've read the GATE guideline on how to build a GATE standalone application. However, I got many errors saying that the creole.xml of each plugins (ANNIE,Twitter, etc) can't be loaded. Here is my code:

```
public class NERGate {
    public NERGate(){}
    public static void main(String args[]) throws GateException, MalformedURLException{
        Gate.setGateHome(new File("/Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1"));
        Gate.setPluginsHome(new File("/Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins"));
        Gate.init();
    }
}
```

And below is the output on my console:

```
Using /Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1 as GATE home
Using /Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins as installed plug-ins directory.
Using /Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/gate.xml as site configuration file.
Using /Users/adibangun/.gate.xml as user configuration file
Using /Users/adibangun/.gate.session as user session file
edu.stanford.nlp.util.Function is available via both the system classpath and a plugin; the plugin classes will be ignored
edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel is available via both the system classpath and a plugin; the plugin classes will be ignored
edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree is available via both the system classpath and a plugin; the plugin classes will be ignored
edu.stanford.nlp.trees.GrammaticalStructureFactory is available via both the system classpath and a plugin; the plugin classes will be ignored
edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger is available via both the system classpath and a plugin; the plugin classes will be ignored
edu.stanford.nlp.process.LexedTokenFactory is available via both the system classpath and a plugin; the plugin classes will be ignored
CREOLE plugin loaded: file:/Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/Stanford_CoreNLP/
Cannot load file:/Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/Twitter/ CREOLE repository.
gate.util.GateException: couldn't open creole.xml
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:299)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:317)
    at gate.Gate.initCreoleRepositories(Gate.java:449)
    at gate.Gate.init(Gate.java:220)
    at thmeaticAnalysis.controller.NERGate.main(NERGate.java:29)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home.GateNERButtonActionPerformed(Home.java:169)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home.access$200(Home.java:24)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home$3.actionPerformed(Home.java:75)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lpt/tumba/spell/SpellChecker;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processParameters(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:502)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processCreoleResourceAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:343)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotationsForResource(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:313)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:283)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:286)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:269)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.processFullCreoleXmlTree(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:365)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.parseDirectory(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:348)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:293)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pt.tumba.spell.SpellChecker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
Cannot load file:/Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/ANNIE/ CREOLE repository.
gate.util.GateException: couldn't open creole.xml
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:299)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:317)
    at gate.Gate.initCreoleRepositories(Gate.java:449)
    at gate.Gate.init(Gate.java:220)
    at thmeaticAnalysis.controller.NERGate.main(NERGate.java:29)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home.GateNERButtonActionPerformed(Home.java:169)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home.access$200(Home.java:24)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home$3.actionPerformed(Home.java:75)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lpt/tumba/spell/SpellChecker;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processParameters(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:502)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processCreoleResourceAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:343)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotationsForResource(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:313)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:283)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:286)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:269)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.processFullCreoleXmlTree(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:365)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.parseDirectory(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:348)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:293)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pt.tumba.spell.SpellChecker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
Cannot load file:/Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/Tools/ CREOLE repository.
gate.util.GateException: couldn't open creole.xml
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:299)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:317)
    at gate.Gate.initCreoleRepositories(Gate.java:449)
    at gate.Gate.init(Gate.java:220)
    at thmeaticAnalysis.controller.NERGate.main(NERGate.java:29)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home.GateNERButtonActionPerformed(Home.java:169)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home.access$200(Home.java:24)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home$3.actionPerformed(Home.java:75)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lpt/tumba/spell/SpellChecker;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processParameters(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:502)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processCreoleResourceAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:343)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotationsForResource(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:313)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:283)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:286)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:269)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.processFullCreoleXmlTree(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:365)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.parseDirectory(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:348)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:293)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pt.tumba.spell.SpellChecker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
Cannot load file:/Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins/Stanford_CoreNLP/ CREOLE repository.
gate.util.GateException: couldn't open creole.xml
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:299)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:317)
    at gate.Gate.initCreoleRepositories(Gate.java:449)
    at gate.Gate.init(Gate.java:220)
    at thmeaticAnalysis.controller.NERGate.main(NERGate.java:29)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home.GateNERButtonActionPerformed(Home.java:169)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home.access$200(Home.java:24)
    at thematicanalysis.GUI.Home$3.actionPerformed(Home.java:75)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lpt/tumba/spell/SpellChecker;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processParameters(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:502)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processCreoleResourceAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:343)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotationsForResource(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:313)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:283)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:286)
    at gate.creole.CreoleAnnotationHandler.processAnnotations(CreoleAnnotationHandler.java:269)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.processFullCreoleXmlTree(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:365)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.parseDirectory(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:348)
    at gate.creole.CreoleRegisterImpl.registerDirectories(CreoleRegisterImpl.java:293)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pt.tumba.spell.SpellChecker
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
```

I wonder if something wrong or weird on my project configuration since I tried to create a new project that solely imported the GATE and it showed no errors when I initialise the Gate using Gate.init().Moreover, all the plugins are exist on my /Applications/GATE_Developer_8.1/plugins with their own creole.xml.
Does anyone know what are the problems? Any comments and suggestions would be really appreciated. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying error on all the plugins is the

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pt.tumba.spell.SpellChecker
```

This class is used by the `Normalizer` PR in the `Twitter` plugin.  The most likely cause I can think of for this error is if you have (accidentally or deliberately) added the `twitter.jar` from GATE's `Twitter` plugin to the main classpath of your application without also adding the `jaspell.jar` file that it depends on.

Ideally you should *not* include *any* plugin JAR files on your main application classpath, but simply let the JARs be loaded by the plugin mechanism in the same way as when you load the plugin into GATE Developer.  This does mean that you can't make static compile-time references to any plugin classes, but in 99% of cases that is not necessary anyway.  All the top-level interfaces like `ProcessingResource`, `LanguageAnalyser`, `CorpusController`, etc. are contained in `gate.jar` so you don't need to `import` a particular PR class in your code to be able to execute it, you can simply cast to `LanguageAnalyser`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now. I did add the twitter.jar separately. Now, after I removed the twitter.jar, it can load all the creole for each plugins. However, I have some new errors but this time those are the different errors. Many Thanks @Ian Roberts